# Send a request from server to Google Analytic instead of the client?

Tags: google-analytics

I'm having a situation were I need to send a 3rd party usage of my data to a webpage that belongs to one of my clients so his google analytics will count the call.

The 3rd party cannot implement the call to my client's webpage on its own, so he can only pass parameters to me.
Now, in order for the call to be counted on my client's side I still need to call his webpage and that the google analytics will count it as a call (with all the user's parameters).

My question is:

1. Is this possible at all and how?
2. If so, what parameters will the 3rd party is required to send me?
3. How do I make the call to my clients webpage with all those parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please look at the [post on my blog about this topic](http://bit.ly/woXICe). You can easily convert it to your favorite language.

Comment: I'm afraid this won't do, since I need to imitate the behavior and data sent to goggle as a regular browser would and not custom/specific parameters.

Comment: You can also use the trick google does in the [server side snippets](http://code.google.com/apis/analytics/docs/mobile/download.html#Download_the_Google_Analytics_server_side_package)

Just have a look around and duplicate the way it proxies the request.